# Fail to convert String @RequestParam to javasql.Timestamp

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

I have a unit test that checks a get request that have a TimeStamp parameter.

The UT mocks a request with the current TimeStemp to String.

```
Timestamp myTimeStamp = new Timestamp(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

MockHttpServletRequestBuilder request =get(REST_PATH).param("horarioFim", mytimeStamp.toString());
```

In my controller I have

```
    @RequestMapping(method = GET)
    public Iterable<AuditVersionModel> search(@RequestParam(required = false) Timestamp horarioFim)
```

TimeStamp is imported from java.sql.TimeStamp

The test fails and I have this information.

```
MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 500
    Error message = null
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json;charset=UTF-8]}
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = {"timestamp":"2020-05-07T23:58:48.298+0000","status":999,"error":"None","message":"Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.sql.Timestamp'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat java.sql.Timestamp] for value '2020-05-07 20:58:48.201'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: \"2020-05-07 20:58:48.201\" is malformed at \" 20:58:48.201\""}
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

I tried to use `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)`  and other variations without success, it is always the same error.

OBS1:This project is a migration from Spring Boot 1.5 to 2.0, the code is simplified.
OBS2: This is a legacy system, the test is the only way to validate the request at the moment.

Comment: @Phil thank you, but that was my mistake posting here, since I need to change the real code.

Comment: `search(@RequestParam(required = false))
       Timestamp horarioFim,` is syntactically invalid. How about you post your actual code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the deserialization framework you are using is expecting the date format to be in ISO format, the date passed in is not in ISO format. I tried passing in "2020-05-07T23:58:48.298+0000" to [OffsetDateTime.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) API and it threw an exception.